# Error in Bidirectional wrapper in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm, bidirectional

I am experimenting the Bidirectional wrapper in Keras, and a sample code is as follows.

```
T = 8
D = 2
M = 3
input_ = Input(shape=(T, D))
rnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(M, return_state=True, return_sequences=True))
#rnn = LSTM(M, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
x = rnn(input_)

model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=x)
X = np.random.randn(1,T,D)
o, h1, c1, h2, c2 = model.predict(X)
```

However, it gives an error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-53f1c7a28b54> in <module>()
19   print("c:", c1)
20 
---> 21 lstm1()

<ipython-input-82-53f1c7a28b54> in lstm1()
8   rnn = Bidirectional(LSTM(M, return_state=True, return_sequences=True))
9   #rnn = LSTM(M, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
---> 10   x = rnn(input_)
```

...

```
ValueError: Tried to convert 'tensor' to a tensor and failed. Error: 
Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2
From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'bidirectional_26/ReverseV2_1
/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?,?,3], [?,3], [?,3].
```

If I remove the Bidirectional wrapper, i.e.

```
rnn = LSTM(M, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
```

then it does not have a problem. Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which version of Keras and TF do you use?

Comment: I had keras 2.0.8 and TF 1.3.0. I have upgraded them to 2.2.0 and 1.8.0 respectively, and the code is working now. Thanks!